# Obtain User ID from a DM message Sent To Bot

Tags: discord.js, userid, dm

I want to find the user id of the person who DMs the bot. Is there any way to do it? I am using Discord.js
I tried by storing member author and member Id but it didn't work. But when I store channel, it store it as authors tag. But the id for that channel does not matches with the id of the user who DM the bot. I am trying to make support mail bot. But it requires the user id so that I can continue the thread by DMing the user. But it's not possible until I get the user id or server member object. And I can't store that DMchannel in my database because i use json for storing datas.

Answer (score 2):

Due to my low reputation, I can't comment, sorry if this does not answer your question.

You can get the ID of the person who DM'd your bot by `message.author.id` (keep in mind, `message` will need to change to whatever variable your message is stored in).
You can also get the channel ID with `message.channel.id`.

The channel ID is not the same as the user's ID (they are two different things), which I assumed you misunderstood from `id for that channel does not matchs with the id of the user who DM the bot`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const client = new discord.Client();

client.login('token here');

/* On message event since you want to 
 * recieve DM and get ID from user who sent DM to your bot.
 */

client.on("message", (msg) => {

  // checks if the message's channel type is 'DM'.
  if(msg.channel.type === "dm") {

    // you can do anything you want here. In my case I put console.log() function.
    // since you wanted user ID, you can use msg.author.id property here.
    console.log(`Recieved DM from ${msg.author.tag}, DM content is`, msg.content);
  }
});
```

Please remember, author/member ID and dm message channel ID is completely separate thing.

Also storing member related data in JSON or an SQL is not a really good idea here. I suggest you only doing that for custom data you've generated, or that would be wasting a lot of memory.

Comment: Add some explanation would be preferred